# Creating a ResourceConfig that behaves the same way as default Jetty's Jersey registering

Tags: java, json, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I have an endpoint with:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String canaryTest(String JSON) {
    return JSON;
}
```

When I register it in Jetty using Jersey

```
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
```

everything seems to work fine.
But in case I try to specify explictly the default config, it stops working (returning a media type error from the endpoint). Even by just passing a default instance of a ResourceConfig to the ServletContainer, it stops working.

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
//config.property(x,defaultX)
//config.property(y,defaultY)
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
```

I'd like to emulate the default configuration behavior manually and explicitly, so what I am asking here is how should I configure ResourceConfig so the behavior keeps working (i.e, what properties to set)

P.S: i'm using Jetty 9.2.6.v20141205 and Jersey 2.14.
Dependencies in Maven:

- org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-server org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-servlet
- org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-servlets
- org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core
- com.sun.jersey.jersey-json
- org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-json-jackson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how you got this to work

```
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
```

I could not produce a working example simply instantiating the `ServletContainer()`. Though I was about to get it to work with the following code

```
public class TestJerseyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.packages("jetty.practice.resources");
        ServletHolder jerseyServlet 
                        = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context 
                = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
        context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Using all your dependencies, excluding the `com.sun.jersey:jersey-json`, as it's not needed. No other configuration. The resource class

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTest() {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.hello = "world";
        return Response.ok(hello).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postHello(Hello hello) {
        return Response.ok(hello.hello).build();
    }

    public static class Hello {
        public String hello;
    }
}
```

in the `jetty.practice.resources` package.

I'm curious to see how you got it to work without the `ResourceConfig`

---

Another thing I should mention is that `jersey-container-servlet-core` should be switched out for `jersey-container-servlet`. The former is for 2.5 container support, but the latter is recommended for 3.x containers. It not have any effect though, with my example

---

cURL

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/test -X POST -d "{\"hello\":\"world\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json"`
>   `world`
>
> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/test`
>   `{"hello":"world"}`

Comment: Could you try it with POST and @Consumes(JSON)? I don't know how I do it but sure org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder holder = new org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder(new org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer()) is compiling and starting the server for me :). Perhaps is that the problem, internally?

Comment: 1) Yes I'll try. 2) Starting the server, but are you able to hit your resources?

Comment: Interesting. You're right it doesn't work. Let me look into it

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. I had a typeo on the `Content-Type` header :-D But it works fine with post also

Comment: One way I could see it working in your case is if you have a webapp structure, as mention [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html), it will have some initial configurations on the implicitly created `ResourceConfig`. But in a standalone structure, I don't see how those rules would apply. That's what has me baffled. That's why I said I am curious to see your code/configuration/structure or whatever to help me understand (more for my benefit, than yours :-)

Comment: My code is pure vainilla, just maven dependencies added and simple code in main and endpoint classes :). No XML config