# Attaching Jersey REST service programmatically to Jetty

Tags: java, rest, gradle, jersey, jetty

Is it possible to attach a Jersey RESTful service to a Jetty runner programmatically? It is not clear to me how to create a Servlet object out of the web service class.

In other words, is it possible to create a Jersey web service without a *web.xml* file and attach it to a server that we would have instantiated ourselves?

**Web Service**

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWebapp {
    @GET()
    public String hello() {
        return "Hi !";
    }
}
```

**Jetty Runner**

```
public class JettyEmbeddedRunner {
    public void startServer() {
        try {
            Server server = new Server();

            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
            context.setContextPath("/test");

            new ServletContextHandler(server, "/app", true, false) {{
                addServlet(new ServletHolder(HelloWorldServlet.class), "/world");
            }};

            server.addConnector(new ServerConnector(server) {{
                 setIdleTimeout(1000);
                 setAcceptQueueSize(10);
                 setPort(8080);
                 setHost("localhost");
            }});
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.0.0.RC2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.0.0.RC2'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you would use in a web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    ...
</sevlet>
```

You can also use the [`ServletContainer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.14/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) for a standalone.

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages("...");
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
```

You can see a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27968094/2587435)

Comment: Thanks!
For future people reading this question. The servlet needs to be attached with:
`context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");`