# How to struggle dependencies problems in maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I have this error for maven-jetty-plugin. I think that this problem happens because of transit dependencies from plugin, which conflict with new libraries. This error appeared after I changed jersey1 to jersey2 and changed all dependencies from com.sun to org.glassfish for server client/core/rs-ws, etc.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run
 (default-cli) on project Plentify: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.je
tty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run failed: An API incompatibility was encounter
ed while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run: java.lang.
NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-m
aven-plugin/9.3.0.M2/jetty-maven-plugin-9.3.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-in
ject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-gu
    ice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aethe
r-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexu
s-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexu
s-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-t
ools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.1/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent
/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-
util/9.3.0.M2/jetty-util-9.3.0.M2.jar
```

And so on...

Can anyone answer how to avoid this kind of errors? Thanks.

UPDATE1: http://pastebin.com/ag2zdiSH link to full pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA SQL Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA NoSQL Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Http Requests core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Common input output operations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Java Bean to JSON and vice versa implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql driver JDBC implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mongo driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- servlet container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- xml json web components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>            
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Authorization -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.authzserver</artifactId>
            <version>${oltu.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.resourceserver</artifactId>
            <version>${oltu.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common</artifactId>
            <version>${oltu.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Scheduler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Query -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.whalin</groupId>
            <artifactId>Memcached-Java-Client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: could you please share the `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: try with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225618/java-restfull-webservice-jax-rs-implementation-with-jersey-2-3-1-libraries)

Comment: I deleted all com.sun.jersey and now it can't find any of my controllers.( Try to solve a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mix `com.sun.jersey` (1.x) dependencies with `org.glassfish.jersey` (2.x) dependencies. They incompatible. The error you are seeing is the result of mixing these together.

All you really need to basic Jersey functionality is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

You can get rid of all the rest (of the Jersey dependencies) you have. For JSON (Jackson) support, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

For Embedded Jetty (noticed your pom packaging is "jar") configuration, see [this complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734049/2587435). The `JacksonFeature` is to configure the Jackson support for JSON.

**EDIT**

After looking at your pom again. I don't see an Jetty dependencies, aside from the plugin. Maybe you're aren't trying to run an embedded instance. For web.xml configuration, you can use this as startup

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            you.can.list.a.comma.separated,
            list.of.packages.to.scan.for,
            resources.and.providers
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- This doesn't really need to be included. 
         Just showing how to add manually. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

One thing that looks odd to me is that you have your packaging as `jar`. You sure it shouldn't be `war` (as it seems from your Jetty plugin configuration, you are running a webapp).

Comment: Thanks. The very first problem was with com.sun.jersey json package. After I removed that code it started working. Then changed servlet com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages to jersey.config.server.provider.packages. Now I have two problems. 1) Server sometimes freezes on start. I need to open terminal window and click some keys, after that it starts working. 2) Interceptors still not found

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two approaches to fix the issue.

First of all I wouldn't use a milestone version of the plugin. I would probably go for a release version or at the very least a release candidate. You could try the `9.3.0.RC1` which is very recent.

If this doesn't solve your issue, you might want to try and update manually the dependency for `javax.ws.rs-api` in your POM. However I have the feeling you would then have troubles with jersey itself. Anyway, giving it a shot won't hurt. To figure out the correct version just use the dependency hierarchy on the POM before update.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>XXX</version>
</dependency>
```