# How to accept JSON POJOs using embedded Jetty?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

How do I configure embedded Jetty and Java Jersey to accept JSON POJO? (The configuration should be done programatically, not in a web.xml file.)

I'm using Jetty 9.4.1 Java Jersey 2.25.1

(I've search through online and more information are for outdated versions of Jetty / Jersey or it is meant for .xml file configuration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it myself. I didn't add any dependency. I just added a method String parameter:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{accountID}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public final Response testPut(String jsonString) { ...
```

and indeed it caught the JSON input String!

Answer (score 1):

If you just add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This should be enough. The required registration of the `JacksonFeature` *should* <sup>**1**</sup> be automatically performed.

<sub>**1** - *should* because if you are creating an uber jar, you need to be careful that you are not overwriting the required file needed for auto-discovery. Generally this can be avoided by using the maven-shade-plugin. This is further discussed in [MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException while running jar from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37737650/2587435).</sub>

**See also:**

- [Jersey: How to Add Jackson to Servlet Holder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734049/2587435) for other ways to manually register the `JacksonFeature`.