# curl to jersey GET won't get to the server

Tags: java, curl, jersey, jetty

I have this server code:

```
@Path("/Sdk")
public class SdkOperation {


    private final CofmanService cofmanService;

    public SdkOperation() throws Exception {
        this(new CofmanServiceNet());
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public SdkOperation(CofmanService cofmanServiceNet) throws Exception {
        this.cofmanService = cofmanServiceNet;
//        SdkServiceConfig.s.initLog();
//        logger.info("SdkServiceConfig.s.LOG4J_PATH= " + SdkServiceConfig.s.LOG4J_PATH);

    }

    @Context
    ServletContext context;

    @Context
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
        return "in SDK Operation test";
    }
```

hosted by embedded Jetty:

```
public class ServerRunner {

    private final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LoggingUtils.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SdkServiceConfig.s.initLog();


        final int port = 8083;

        final Server jettyServer = new Server(port);
        final HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

        // Creating the first web application context
        final WebAppContext webappContext = new WebAppContext();


        webappContext.setExtractWAR(false);
        handlers.addHandler(webappContext);

        // Adding the handlers to the server.
        jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("failed to init jetty server", ex);
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
    }       
}
```

I try curl command and don't see any breakpoint stop on the server. What am I missing?

```
curl http://localhost:8083/Sdk/test
```

When i call via browser i get:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /Sdk/test. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.15.v20161220
```

Comment: are you able to acess it via browser , write some log in  test and then check

Comment: Don't use need to set the war location for WebAppContext?

Comment: @gladiator I get: HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /Sdk/test. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.15.v20161220

Comment: @peeskillet it's a jar. no war. just API

Comment: Well then how do you expect Jersey to run, when you haven't configured it? I though maybe you were trying to use a bundled war which has all the Jersey configuration. Obviously it's not going to work if you don't actually configure Jersey. Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734049/2587435)

Comment: 503 means some internal error check the logs

Answer (score 0):

As far as you add `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` you should add `-H "Content-Type:text/xml"` to curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/xml" http://localhost:8083/Sdk/test
```

Comment: but even when i call via browser i get: HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /Sdk/test. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.15.v20161220